# compile dust templates into one javascript file

Tags: javascript, templating, dust.js

I'm using `dustc`, which is shipped with `dustjs-linkedin`, to compile my templates. However, it only allows me to compile one template at a time. So I keep two directories, `templates/` and `js/templates/` and use the following script to compile them in one go:

```
#!/bin/bash
for name in `ls templates/ | grep -o -P '^[^.]+'`; do
  dustc --name=$name templates/$name.html js/templates/$name.js
done
```

However, in this way, the templates are in different JS files. All of them are in the same pattern:

```
(function(){dust.register("xxx",body_0);function body_0(chk,ctx){...}return body_0;})();
```

This could potentially lead to large amounts of unnecessary bytes downloaded by a browser. So I wish to compile the templates into one JS file, or combine the compiled JS files together. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what is the exact issue, but if you are looking to just combine the files, then using a dependency manager like sprockets or require.js's optimizer tool will do the trick.

the fact that they are in the same pattern when brought into the same file doesn't do anything - they are all enclosed in the anonymous self executing function to protect namespace.

if, on the other hand, you are trying to optimize the code by removing duplicate patterns, then i suggest using uglifyjs or google's closure compiler to do so automatically.

combining and minimizing the code should not be an issue at all - it will work just well :)  hope this helps

Comment: Thx. After using dust.js for a while, I found this pattern is not that common. Hope uglifyjs can optimize that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Duster.js](https://github.com/dmix/dusterjs) (automatic dust watch & precompile for node.js) and [r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) for combining into one file.